# NavigationFolders.add() crashes Outlook for shared calendars?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

Simple enough line here:

Set navFol = navGroup.NavigationFolders.Add(cal)

This works as expected for any local calendars, but it instantly crashes Outlook if "cal" is a shared calendar. Anyone know a workaround to move shared calendars around between navigation folders? I'm quite new to VBA, just hacking my way around to get a macro to do a simple something for me -- or at least something which really should be simple if not for this.

I doubt it matters, but just in case, "cal" is being set in a for loop by iterating through a list of EntryIDs like so:

Set cal = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetFolderFromID(str)

And it's not the variable assignment that's failing there (which is why the above line should be irrelevant). I can do anything else with the calendar whether or not it's shared: read the name, grab appointments from it, etc. Outlook just apparently does not like using shared calendars as arguments for NavigationFolders.Add().

EDIT: I'm talking about NON-default calendars shared via sharing invitations. GetDefaultSharedFolder or the like isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Namespace class to get the shared folder instead.

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  
 myRecipient.Resolve  
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
  Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If  
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = _  
 myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _  
 (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)  
 CalendarFolder.Display  
End Sub
```

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870053(v=office.15).aspx) method of the NavigationFolders class adds the specified Folder, as a NavigationFolder object, to the end of the NavigationFolders collection.

Comment: I'm not looking for default folders, though. I'm talking about non-default calendars shared with a sharing invitation.